# Postman: how to verify a value

Tags: arrays, json, postman

I am sending a request to list the articles written by Author 6188.

I have the following response:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to write a test case to verify that the `AuthorID` key has a value of `6188`.

I don't want the test case to fail if there are other `Author ID`s, it should fail only if `AuthorID` 6188 is not found.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick check that would look at the `AuthorID` to see if the value is one of the ones specified:

```
pm.test("Check Author ID", () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().Authors, (arrItem) => {
        pm.expect(arrItem.AuthorID).to.be.oneOf([8575,8576,8577])
    })
})
```

If an ID value is not in the list, then the check would fail. It's not the most robust check and there are other ways to do this but hopefully, it's something to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks Danny.I have a small doubt cz the test case pass even when i send a request where response does not contain 8576 as AuthorID as well.

Comment: What is the exact response data? Your example is not valid. Update the question with details about what you have tried so far and attach images. More information will help you get a better answer.

Comment: Hi Danny, I edited the comment and attached a screenshot.

Comment: You're missing the top part of the response, the key the you want is nested within other keys. My answer would work if you change `pm.response.json().Authors` to `pm.response.json().key.key.Authors` - replacing key with the values for you JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following but the test fails, since it has multiple Author IDs.

```
pm.test("Author ID is Correct", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.AuthorID).to.include(6188);
```

});